# Redirect https to https://www

Tags: redirect, nginx

At present i use this to redirect `domain.com` to `https://www.domain.com`

```
server {
    #listen 80 is default
    server_name domain.com;
    return 301 https://www.domain.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen       443 ; 
    server_name  www.domain.com;
    //rest of config goes here
}
```

However some part of it is flawed since `https://domain.com` is not redirected to `https://www.domain.com`

Any idea of how to  modify the above to achieve that objective....

Comment: Try to change `server_name  www.domain.com;` to `server_name  domain.com;` for the 443 section, and redirect it to `www.domain.com`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed it by adding another server block to catch the non www ssl

**Kind regards to Mohammad AbuShady for the tip**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate    /etc/ssl/domain_bundle.crt; 
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/domain.key.nopass;
    ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:AES256-SHA256:RC4:HIGH:!MD5:!aNULL:!eNULL:!NULL:!DH:!EDH:!AESGCM;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    server_name domain.com;
    return 301 https://www.domain.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen       443 ; 
    server_name  www.domain.com;
    //rest of config goes here
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You didn't set a server to catch the non www ssl, you can fix that by making the same redirect server catch both

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443; # add this line
    server_name domain.com;
    return 301 https://www.domain.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen       443 ; 
    server_name  www.domain.com;
    //rest of config goes here
}
```

Comment: getting `SSL connection error` connection error with chrome when applying your fix

Comment: Do you have an ssl certificate ?

Comment: Ok just noticed you already figured it out, The error was because the ssl needed the key and certificate, you can merge the blocks by adding listen 80 so the same block would serve both ssl and non ssl, no need for separate server blocks.